# Android - SQLCipher

Tags: android, sqlcipher

This is my demo project

```
public class SQLDemoActivity extends Activity {
    EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //you must set Context on SQLiteDatabase first
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
        String password = "foo123";
        eventsData = new EventDataSQLHelper(this);
        //then you can open the database using a password
        SQLiteDatabase db = eventsData.getWritableDatabase(password);
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            addEvent("Hello Android Event: " + i, db);
        db.close();
        db = eventsData.getReadableDatabase(password);
        Cursor cursor = getEvents(db);
        showEvents(cursor);
        db.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        eventsData.close();
    }
    private void addEvent(String title, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(EventDataSQLHelper.TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(EventDataSQLHelper.TITLE, title);
        db.insert(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, values);
    }
    private Cursor getEvents(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor cursor = db.query(EventDataSQLHelper.TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        return cursor;
    }
    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder("Saved Events:\n\n");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            long id = cursor.getLong(0);
            long time = cursor.getLong(1);
            String title = cursor.getString(2);
            ret.append(id + ": " + time + ": " + title + "\n");
        }
        Log.i("sqldemo",ret.toString());
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error how i clean the errors. The following links as demo project is https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher.

```
04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load stlport_shared: findLibrary returned null

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:142)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:137)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at example.SQLDemoActivity.onCreate(SQLDemoActivity.java:20)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

04-12 12:53:20.229: E/AndroidRuntime(7413):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)<
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your project has the `libs/` directory contents set up properly. Not only do you need JAR files, but you need subdirectories with `.so` files for each CPU architecture that you intend to support, such as you see in the `libs/` directory of [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure).

Comment: i have the same error , i did your solution but it keeps throwing the above exception , note i am using AndroidStudio 0.5.1 and using Emulator kitkat .

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Here the solution that worked for me.

Create a folder named jniLibs near your java folder and place there all directories (or just directories which architecture you intend to support) with *.so files.

It must look like this.

[image]

If it works for you, you don't need to have this folders in your libs folder.

P.S. I use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Within your App, inside your build.gradle file make sure you have the following lines:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/sqlcipher-javadoc.jar')
compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
```

}

Also right click your project, open module settings and select the dependencies tab. Make sure sqlcipher-javadoc.jar and sqlcipher.jar is listed.